# Preserving marker size when using hue, row, or column in lmplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I noticed that when you use an lmplot and add hue along with a marker size as a series, it no longer preserves the marker size.  Using seaborn tips, here is an exmample:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips['marker_size'] = tips['size']*20    
g = sns.lmplot(x="tip", y="total_bill"
               #,hue="smoker"
               #,row="sex"
               #, col="time"
               ,fit_reg=False
               ,data=tips, size=8, aspect=.7, scatter_kws={'s': tips['marker_size']})
plt.show()
```

Once you uncomment hue, row, or col the marker sizes are no longer preserved.  I'd like to preserve the absolute marker sizes for each point even when they're separated by color and grid.  I suspect that separating by hue, row, or col changes the sort order of the list.

[Notice this is the largest point with no hue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPbAn.png)

[With hue, now it is smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFnP7.png)

Comment: can you show us how you get/make `tips`? otherwise, we can't verify the behaviour you are talking about (the issue may be relevant to other code not shown here)

Comment: I just added the line.  Thanks.